# iOS Simulator allow cordova geolocation, using ionic framework

Tags: ios, geolocation, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm testing my cordova geolocation in my iOS simulator. When I called the function a message popped up asking if i would allow my app to use my current geolocation and I accidentally clicked "don't allow" now it just errors when i hit the button how do i change that to allow.

Might help:

```
 $scope.getCurrentLocation = function(){
    var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude

        console.log(lat, long);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to go into the setting on the emulator and reset the permission on the application for geolocation

Comment: Hi Aaron is the default long and lat of the simulator dynamic.. Like when i bring my laptop over to a different location would it change?? just wondering

Comment: in xcode you can simulate location on the debug menu